# UITableView swipe action delete and edit with custom view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am setting view when swipe tableview cell like as 1st view in table it need to be stick on as second view and change its color.

Is it possible in Swift 4 and iOS?

[image]

Comment: You want to changed the second cell when swiping the first one?

Comment: no i want first cell like second when i swipe first cell

Comment: Should it be actually swiped(moved left or right) or you are just using the swipe gesture?

Comment: using gesture no need to move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are getting the swipe gesture in view controller you do the next:

```
func didSwipe(_ cell: UITableViewCell) {
   let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
   if indexPath.row + 1 < myViewModels.count - 1 {
     // Store the info from the next view model to the current one
     myViewModels[indexPath.row].update(with: myViewModels[indexPath.row + 1])
     tableView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
   }
}
```

myViewModels is an array of object(contains data, colors, etc) that you are displaying
Instead of update you can manually update necessary fields

The code may have an errors but the idea should be clear